# Spline options for interpolating between control points on a population curve?

Tags: c++, interpolation, spline

I'm looking to model population curves using an interpolative spline between 7 control points. My problem is that I can't find any grokkable/digestable coding/math resource that compares the pros and cons of various splines in layman's terms.

First, here's a simplified illustration of the population curve in my code:

```
struct CurvePoint {
public:
    short height; // the point's height along a population curve, measured as age in years (can be negative, representing a building trend whose peak/valley will happen in the future)
    double width; // the (nonnegative) width of the population curve at this point, measured as number of people **born within a single year**
    // Each CurvePoint represents one "bar" of a population pyramid that's one year tall.
};

class PopulationCurve {
public:
    std::array<CurvePoint, 7> control_points; // assumes that control_points[i].height < control_points[i + 1].height and that control_points[i].width >= 0
    // control_points[0] is the young end of the curve (typically a nonpositive number; see above)
    // control_points[6] is the old end of the curve (typically representing the longevity of the population; if so, control_points[6].width will be 0 since no one is left alive at that point)

    std::vector<CurvePoint> constructCurve() {
        std::vector<CurvePoint> curve;
        short youngest_age = control_points[0].height;
        short oldest_age = control_points[6].height;
        for (auto a = youngest_age; a <= oldest_age; ++a) {
            CurvePoint p;
            p.height = a;
            // p.width = ??? (the interpolated width at age a)
            curve.push_back(p);
        }
        return curve;
    }
    void deconstructCurve(std::vector<CurvePoint> curve) {
        std::array<CurvePoint, 7> sampled_control_points;
        // ??? (turn point samples from the input curve into control points as appropriate)
        control_points = sampled_control_points;
    }
};
```

The hardcoding of 7 control points is intentional. I'm implementing a choice between two compression schemes: virtually lossless compression of 7 control points in 44 bytes, and lossy compression of 7 control points in 20 bytes (my application is currently more memory/disk-limited than CPU-limited). I don't believe those compression schemes are relevant to the question, but let me know if I need to show their code, especially if there's a good reason I should be considering <7 or >7 control points.

Here are the criteria I'm looking for in a spline, **in descending order of importance**:

1. Interpolation between all control points. This is by far the most important criterion; otherwise, I would've used a Bézier curve or b-spline.
2. Interpolation between the first and last control point *only*. If all points aren't interpolated between, then only the first and last can be (i.e. what a Bézier curve or b-spline would've got me).
3. Fast constructability + deconstructability. There's a near-1:1 correlation between `constructCurve()` and `deconstructCurve()`; almost every call to construct will eventually be followed up by a call to deconstruct, so I'm only interested in the combined performance and the not the performance of either one individually. That being said, while I'm very interested in memory/disk optimization right now, I am not going to prematurely optimize speed, so this is a consideration only.
4. Reasonably accurate deconstructability.
5. Lossless deconstructability if no changes to the curve are made. i.e. If `deconstructCurve(constructCurve());` is called, `control_points` will remain the same.
6. Prettiness =) (since linear interpolation between control points *is* the best match for the rest of the criteria...)

I didn't post this question on math since it's not entirely language-agnostic and contains C++ code. I didn't post it on gamedev since it's a question of implementation and not design.

Comment: In `CurvePoint`, should `height` really be an integer type?  If a population is broken up into 6 or 7 chunks, with each chunk representing `width` individuals, it seems inappropriate to represent their average age as an integer.  And even if integral precision is acceptable here, interpolating between `height` values would need to be performed using floating-point math, but when forced back to an integer value, the result could give a sort of "stair step" effect instead of a smooth transition, depending on the sampled data.

Comment: Also, how do you want `width` be treated in the interpolated  series?  Should it be interpolated between sample `width`s? And if so, should normalization be performed, so the sum of the interpolated `width`s is equal to the sum of the samples' `width`s?

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Oh! I needed to explain this: Σ `control_points[p].width` is **not** the total population size. Each `control_points[p].width` is the number of people that are `control_points[p].height` years old (i.e. `width` only represents the number of people born within a single year). The total population size is  Σ `curve[p].width` as returned by `constructCurve()`. So, the population size isn't defined by the control points but is instead a function of `constructCurve()`—I don't need control over the population size; just the control points. I need to edit all that in.

Comment: Also, `height` is an integer type partially because it's designed to be incremented annually. The simplest annual update for a population will increment each `control_points[p].height` and scale `control_points[p].width` downward using a mortality multiplier.

Comment: Hm, you've got me thinking that I should be more explicit about this being more of a population *pyramid* rather than *curve*. It will be drawn as a curve regardless, but maybe I should be thinking of representing it as a bar diagram of cohorts/age groups within code.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Sorry, clarification for my first comment: The total population size is Σ `curve[p].width` **once per `round(curve[p].height)`**. The specifics of which I imagine may depend on the interpolation used?

Comment: Actually, forget rounding `curve[p].height`, I could use some variation on `(curve[p].height - curve[p-1].height) * curve[p].width`. Anyway—I have options that I'll hash out once I have the curve interpolated.

Comment: I did understand that the sum of the 7 sampled `width` values would be the total sampled population -- I was just wondering if the (~44 or whatever)  interpolated series `width` values should also sum to the same value, but it sounds like `width` in the interpolated series is not important.  Graphically, I would expect these kind of data to be represented as a distribution or histogram, with age on the horizontal axis, and the curve's vertical "height" representing the relative size of each age's subpopulation.  continued...

Comment: In addition, the `width` value could be important to the interpolation, depending on how each `height` (age category) is chosen.  If each age category increases by the same amount from one sample to the next, then interpolation can ignore `width`.  However, if each age category is arbitrarily determined, `width` carries some information about the sample's significance or weight which should be taken into account.